# How to work with dates fast in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have dataframe with 200000 rows. Each record has a timestamp, and I need to group them by date. So I do:

```
In [67]: df['result_date'][0]
Out[67]: Timestamp('2017-09-01 09:12:00')

In [68]: %timeit df['result_day'] = df['result_date'].apply(lambda x: str(x.date()))
2.26 s ± 73.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [69]: df['result_day'][0]
Out[69]: '2017-09-01'
```

or

```
In [70]: %timeit df['result_day'] = df['result_date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
2.05 s ± 213 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [71]: df['result_day'][0]
Out[71]: datetime.date(2017, 9, 1)
```

anyway, it takes ~2 seconds. Can I do it faster?

UPD:

```
In [75]: df.shape
Out[75]: (228217, 18)

In [77]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.date
1.44 s ± 42.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the example from jezrael. You almost *never* want to actually use `.date`; this creates python objects. `.normalize()` sets the time on dates to 00:00:00, effectively making them dates, but keeping them in a high performance format of `datetime64[ns]`.

```
In [32]: rng = pd.date_range('2000-04-03', periods=200000, freq='2H')
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'result_date': rng})  
    ...: 

In [33]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.date
482 ms ± 10.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [34]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.normalize()
16.3 ms ± 234 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Grouping

```
In [39]: %timeit df.groupby(df['result_date'].dt.date).size()
506 ms ± 11.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [40]: %timeit df.groupby(df['result_date'].dt.normalize()).size()
24.2 ms ± 1.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Or idiomatically

```
In [38]: %timeit df.resample('D', on='result_date').size()
5.47 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: What about `floor` ? It is faster as `normalize`.

Comment: yep that’s reasonable, but canonical is .normalize()

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), which working also with `NaT` very nice:

```
df['result_day'] = df['result_date'].dt.date
```

---

```
rng = pd.date_range('2000-04-03', periods=200000, freq='2H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'result_date': rng})  

In [216]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.date
1 loop, best of 3: 474 ms per loop

In [217]: %timeit df['result_date'].apply(lambda x: str(x.date()))
1 loop, best of 3: 740 ms per loop

In [218]: %timeit df['result_date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
1 loop, best of 3: 559 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

I think [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) is faster as [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
#home's notebook, so different times as above

In [3]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.date
1 loop, best of 3: 854 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.normalize()
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.floor('D')
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df.groupby(df['result_date'].dt.date).size()
1 loop, best of 3: 883 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df.groupby(df['result_date'].dt.normalize()).size()
10 loops, best of 3: 40.2 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit df.groupby(df['result_date'].dt.floor('D')).size()
10 loops, best of 3: 25.9 ms per loop
```

EDIT1:

`numpy` alternative is faster, but as pointed [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034229/how-to-work-with-dates-fast-in-pandas/47034240?noredirect=1#comment81170603_47034240):

> it’s faster but you lose things like time zones and any higher level methods.

```
In [9]: %timeit df['result_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.39 ms per loop
```

Comment: In my case it is faster but not so fast as yours: `In [77]: %timeit df['result_date'].dt.date`
`1.44 s ± 42.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: i am not sure why you show numpy at all; sure it’s faster but you lose things like time zones and any higher level methods. this is just confusing to most users.

Comment: It is True, so added to answer.